# MySQL How to check for qty of intersecting dates with a range?

Tags: mysql

I can query quantities based on `'date'` OR `'dateLast'` but do not understand how to get a quantity when the date is between `'date'` and `'dateLast'`

This query works and shows the basic logic but it does not use the `'endDate'` to determine dates in between. How do I iterate the in between dates to check against a value (7) to collect those that are over?

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateLast` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mid` int
);

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `date`, `dateLast`, `mid`) VALUES
(1, '2019-03-19', '2019-03-21', 22),
(2, '2019-03-18', '2019-03-25', 22),
(3, '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', 22),
(4, '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', 22),
(5, '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', 22),
(6, '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', 22),
(7, '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', 22),
(8, '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', 22),
(9, '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', 22);
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    reservations.date,
    COUNT(*) AS Qty
FROM
    reservations
WHERE
    reservations.mid = 22
    AND Qty >=7
GROUP BY
    reservations.date
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried SQL Fiddle but it just waits for loading. Created a test in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nUoM5DymGwNsmcb2CGVYnr/1 but if fails to work like my version of MySQL 5.7
I believe  I can not achieve my goal in SQL alone and am moving to a PHP Array of dates and a custom function for the intersections and counts.

Comment: Well, that's the least important part of the linked answer provided

Comment: Point being, further research has me thinking it's not possible to achieve in a single SQL Query. I could be wrong which is why I am looking for a solution, but at this point, PHP may be more successful.

Comment: You might well be right. But on the basis of the information thus far provided, we can't really say.